# How to define an application wide ids with Rails 5 on PostgreSQL 9.4.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I thought I had the solution here: [application-wide sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607727/ruby-on-rails-how-to-generate-an-application-wide-sequence)
It looks like behaviour has changed since Rails 5.

I define a specific sequence to handle my objects ids:

```
class BusinessRule < ActiveRecord::Base

### id generation
  self.sequence_name = "objects_seq"
```

The migration, (which ran before I edit the model), generated a sequence for Business Rules:

> business_rules_id_seq

And this sequence is referenced in the COLUMN_DEF attribute of the business_rules.id column.

Despite the **self.sequence_name** directive, ActiveRecord still uses the conventional sequence **business_rules_id_seq**. Deleting the sequence does not change a thing.

Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret "The migration, (which ran before I edit the model)" as the following:

1. You ran migrations to create the table
2. You then updated the model with the `sequence_name`

If this is correct, I suspect that you need to either

1. Have to add the sequence in the model before migrations, or
2. Look at this question for [explicitly setting sequences on migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680777/1146473)